# Type Mismatch error when inserting formula in cell

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I am trying to insert a formula into column K of Sheet1 in current workbook, based on the worksheet name selected by the user. the formula string shows perfectly fine, but it gives me a type mismatch error.

```
Private Sub Select_Sheet_Click()

Dim counter, row_index As Long
Dim formula As Variant
If Sheet_List.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox ("A worksheet must be selected from the list to continue")
    Exit Sub
Else
    UserForm1.Hide
    With ThisWorkbook
    For row_index = 2 To 12
        formula = "=VLOOKUP(J" & row_index & ",'[" & file_name & "]" & Sheet_List.Value & "'!$J:$K,2,FALSE)"
        MsgBox (formula)
        
        Sheets(Sheet1).Range("K" & row_index).formula = formula
        
    Next row_index
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

[image]

I have tried the following

- set formula datatype as string and as variant
- range.value and range.Formula and range.FormulaR1C1
- instead of creating the "formula" string, i have also tried directly, i.e:  range.formula = "=VLOOKUP(J" & row_index ....

EDIT: Code fails on the row: '''Sheets(Sheet1).Range("K" & row_index).formula = formula'''

Comment: Where is the code failing?  What line?  Where are you assigning `Sheet_List.Value` and what is it supposed to be?

Comment: code fails on the row '''Sheets(Sheet1).Range("K" & row_index).formula = formula'''

Comment: sheet_list.value is being selected in the user form. the value is showing correct (that's why i added the msgbox to check)

Answer (score 3):

## Answer

For the row you are indicating as the problem, you have a syntax error:

```
Sheets(Sheet1).Range("K" & row_index).formula = formula
```

should instead be:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & row_index).formula = formula
```

or possibly (this is less preferred I think, but uses worksheet code name)

```
Sheet1.Range("K" & row_index).formula = formula
```

### Other things to consider

Your use of a `With; End With` statement isn't doing anything because you have no dot (.) objects inside the statements.  I use them all the time -- they're great -- but you're not getting any benefit here.

It works, but I really personally hate to use variable names which can be confused with objects, properties, or methods in the language.  In this case, your use of the string variable `formula` is at least visually in conflict with the `Range.Formula` property.  It works... but I'd recommend avoiding doing that.

Instead of using the `MsgBox()` to display your formula and check it, you should look at `Debug.Print`.  Doesn't stop your code, and you get a nice list in the Immediate Window.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I have also instituted your suggestions for making the code better.

Comment: Excellent.  Glad I was able to help you.  When you're completely satisfied with the answer, be sure to mark this as the accepted answer and clear it from the queue.  But only if you're satisfied it answered your question.